# AnalyticsHashTagWebPart Showing No Results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, social, hashtags

I have inherited a problem on a SharePoint 2013 on a project I have just recently joined. In the My Sites area of the SharePoint is the `AnalyticsHashTagWebPart` which shows as "Trending #tags". This web part always shows "Tagging's been quiet lately. No trending tags right now".

I am aware that on page load the part will (should) initiate a search for tags. Using Firefox tools I can see the requests for the tags are not being sent. The results should come back as JSON.

A few gotchas found by others is messing around with the search crawls and breaking it, that does not seem to be the issue.

The page is customized, which makes this more difficult. The changes are not mine so I am still figuring out what could be the issue. Looking at the part markup I see nothing different from the OOTB webpart.

- I have Continuous crawls set up
- I have tested a tag search in the search service (Manage Query Rules)
  and it came back highlighting the `Tags in Sharepoint Search` OOTB
  rule. So it seems that works.

There are enough posts in the last few days, as I have had some created with tags, so there should be trending.

Any ideas on where else to look to find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help someone else in the future, and maybe save them days of searching. It turned out the Managed Property `Tags` was no longer mapping to the crawled property `ows_taxId_MetadataAllTagsInfo`