# Conversations not showing in search results

Tags: search, newsfeed

I'm experiencing an issue where every other aspect of Search seems to be working as expected but when I do a search and select "Conversation" nothing ever shows. If I go directly to the results type page (`conversationresults.aspx`), I see a few things but not much. I'm not even sure where to start here. The result type exists and has never been modified. People search and all other types of search are working fine. I have no errors on any of my content sources.

Some additional details have come to light. Discussions appearing on Community Sites are showing in search almost immediately in the conversation search but I'm still not getting anything from the news feed and the "Trending Tags" web part is not showing anything either.

I have verified the issue discussed [in this question (AnalyticsHashTagWebPart Showing No Results)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84511/analyticshashtagwebpart-showing-no-results) is not what is causing me problem.

Comment: Do you have any crawl rules or scopes with custom rules to exclude content?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that at all. The only customization other than creating the content sources was a single result type that uses a custom display template.

Comment: It seems that the "trending tags" web part is not showing any tags, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone had messed with the content sources. I added the newsfeed URL back to content sources and started a crawl and just like magic, conversations started showing in the results. I think the "Trending Tags" issue is not related.